# _grokparsefailure because of double/single quote?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have read about double single quote for whatever strings. I have no idea how it works. Can someone enlighten me? Because I have been getting some rows as `_grokparsefailure`. I have 21 thousand of rows and only 16 thousand of rows managed to parse successfully.. Any help?

In logstash's config:

```
grok {
    match => [ 'message', '%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:action}%{SPACE}%{DATA:logsource} %{DATA:interface} %{GREEDYDATA:kvpairs}' ]
}
```

This is the sample rows of data I have:

```
Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 70.77.116.190; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2612;
Jan 1 22:54:22 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 61.164.41.144; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: udp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 5060; s_port: 5069;
Jan 1 22:54:23 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 69.55.245.136; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2970;
Jan 1 22:54:41 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 95.104.65.30; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2565;
Jan 1 22:54:43 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 222.186.24.11; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 2967; s_port: 6000;
Jan 1 22:54:54 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 74.204.108.202; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: udp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 137; s_port: 53038;
Jan 1 22:55:10 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 71.111.186.26; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 38548;
Jan 1 23:02:56 accept %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 inzone: External; outzone: Local; rule: 3; rule_uid: {723F81EF-75C9-4CBB-8913-0EBB3686E0F7}; service_id: icmp-proto; ICMP: Echo Request; src: 24.188.22.101; dst: %DSTIP%; proto:
```

What changes do I have to make in this line to make all my rows getting parsed successfully? I did use grokdebugger and I had no error.

Comment: Can you show a sample log line that you know has not been parsed successfully?

Comment: I tried all your given log lines with your config and logstash parses them properly without a single error. Can you provide some failed lines? Apart from that, in your config example there is no difference between double or single quotes. Just decide consistently for one format. The quotes are important for escaping or when specifying a config from command line.

Comment: Is there a way to send a file? Because I'm not sure which rows have not been successfully parsed.. 21 thousand of rows

Comment: You can [gist them](https://gist.github.com/) or zip them and share them via dropbox or similar

Comment: Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/nthispain/8b062b35102f13af201d)! Tried to solve it earlier on but haven't been successful yet :/

Comment: I've been able to load all the 21678 lines of your log file without any issue and no grok parse failures. Note that I'm using logstash 1.5.3. How does your `file` input look like?

Comment: Really? I have it. How do I check what version of logstash I'm currently using? Here's the [file](https://gist.github.com/nthispain/51305965475c0e7613ed)

Comment: You can ignore the `template overwrite` and `template` under `output` plugin